# Problem with assigning different colors to segments in PointCloud

Tags: ros, c++, ar-kinect, pointcloud

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am trying a segment tracking algorithm. Right now I have 2 segments. I am coloring each segment with different RGB values, pushing the segments into output_cloud which is pcl::PointCloud2pcl::PointXYZRGB and publishing the output cloud.

The issue I am facing is when I see the PointCloud from RVIZ, I am getting only a single color for both (all) the segments. I have checked the correctness of assigning the RGB values by doing this:

```
 // checking colors 
        int prev_r = 0;
        int prev_g = 0;
        int prev_b = 0;

        int counter = 0;
            
        for (pcl::PointXYZRGB point : output_cloud) {
            if (prev_r != point.r) {
                std::cout << int(point.r) << " " << int(point.g) << " " << int(point.b) << std::endl;
                std::cout << counter << std::endl;
                counter = 0;
            }
            prev_r = point.r;
            prev_g = point.g;
            prev_b = point.b;
            counter++;
        }
        std::cout << counter << std::endl;

        pub_cloud.publish(output_cloud);
```

This is what I get (which I think is correct):

```
Size of segNo_cloud[0] :1168
Size of output_cloud: 1168
Size of segNo_cloud[1] :40680
Size of output_cloud: 41848
16 85 230
0
210 15 236
1168
40680
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/383659/problem-with-assigning-different-colors-to-segments-in-pointcloud/) by [nayan](https://answers.ros.org/users/79277/nayan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 26 on 2021-08-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

**Update:** I **fixed** the issue! Everything was correct, but I was not clearing the vectors after assigning the segments due to which some segments were overwritten. Hope this helps someone :)

---

Originally posted by [nayan](https://answers.ros.org/users/79277/nayan/) with karma: 26 on 2021-08-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0